# How to register a nested generic type?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to do this:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestHandler<MyCommand<>>), typeof(MyCommandHandler<>));
```

The compiler is giving me this error:

> Unexpected use of an unbound generic name

But it must be possible to register a generic without specifying the generics, right?

`MyCommandHandlerM<T>` looks like this:

```
public class MyCommandHandler<T> : IRequestHandler<MyCommand<T>> where TPayload : class
```

I get the error on this piece of code:

```
typeof(IRequestHandler<UitvalCommand<>>)
```

Comment: The number of `<` and `>`, as well as `(` and `)` in your code doesn't match: there's 3 `<` but 4 `>` in your code, and 3 `(` but 2 `)`. Can you first fix your line so it compiles?

Comment: On another note, it looks like you're mixing two different `AddTransient` syntaxes. One syntax is `.AddTransient<Class1, Class2>();`, and the other is `.AddTransient(typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2));`. (notice how both parameters used `typeof`, not just one). The second one allows you to use unbound generics.

Comment: @Orion You are right, I have updated the code, but I still keep the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid generics don't work that way - under the hood, generics just create multiple classes at compile time that are 'concrete' with the specified types given to them - so if your code uses a `MyCommandHander<string>`, then effectively a type will be generated under the hood for that specific version of the generic type. This means you cannot have generic type wildcards like you're trying to do, as the compiler doesn't know what 'concrete' type to generate or reference.

Probably the easiest way forward is to create a non-generic interface or base class that `MyCommandHandler<T>` implements, and use that instead of trying to use `MyCommandHandler<>`. For example:

```cs
public interface IMyCommandHandler { ... }
public class MyCommandHandler<T> : IMyCommandHandler, IRequestHandler<MyCommand<T>> where TPayload : class
```

And then replace references to `MyCommandHandler<>` with `IMyCommandHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

John's answer is useful and my answer will be in parallel and try to clarify the issue. First, nested generic types complicate the situation here and I would simplify the code. Consider the following:

```
interface IFoo<T> {}

class Foo<T> : IFoo<T> {}
```

Note that both `IFoo` and `Foo` *have the same generic type parameter of* `T`. Now this line will successfully register the service:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(Foo<>));
```

If you have a chance to redesign your code so that it adapts to this structure (similar to John's answer) then you will be done.